# macOS Big Sur Reminders.app not connecting to SOGo CalDav server with weird symptoms

Tags: mac, ssl, calendar, macos-bigsur, caldav

I've recently upgraded to from Mojave to Big Sur and I'm having trouble connecting to my gandi.net SOGo CalDAV account, with some weird symptoms:

1. The account & connection worked on Mojave
2. The account & connection work on my iOS14 iPhone
3. Calendar.app works over the same CalDAV connection (i.e. account is working)
4. Thunderbird can see both calendar and tasks/reminder (i.e. not a firewall issue)
5. The certificate seems to satisfy Apple's [new requirements](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210176) (SHA2, SAN, <800 days)

I've used [gandi's instructions](https://docs.gandi.net/en/gandimail/sogo_webmail/caldav.html#sync-with-apple-ical) to set up my connection, and unfortunately the helpdesk is referring me to Apple.

I've sniffed the SSL traffic and it seems the Reminders.app is looking in the wrong directory(?), and getting quite some 4xx status codes:

[caldav traffic of reminders.app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRmms.png)

Any ideas what (else) it can be?

Comment: I have the same issue and I also notice that the Calendar app in macOS will notify me about a past reminder again, and again, and again, even though I choose "Complete" on the notification. I cannot find the corresponding entry in the Calendar app, nor in the Reminders app. I think these events are likely related.

Answer (score 0):

My hypothesis is that Apple is dropping support for CalDAV, per [BusyCal's post here](https://support.busymac.com/blog/112990). There's also few alternatives that support CalDAV, most clients have their proprietary implementation. However, I did find:

1. [Rainlendar Pro](https://www.rainlendar.net/) - 10 EUR
2. [2Do](https://www.2doapp.com/) - 60 USD
3. [Busycal](https://busymac.com/busycal/) - 50 USD

See more in [this overview](https://devguide.calconnect.org/CalDAV/Client-Implementations).